# RestKit with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: asihttprequest, restkit

Is it possible use RESTKit with ASIHTTPRequest?

I have been using ASIHTTPRequest but it seems to be deprecated and I read that RESTKit is the newer library. I just want to know if I can fall back to ASIHTTPRequest if I need to later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use them together, but general you should be ok replacing ASIHTTPRequest with RESTKit. For a way to combine the two, you can see here: 
[ASIHTTPRequest backed RestKit object mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191714/asihttprequest-backed-restkit-object-mapping/10204511#10204511)