# Faking http connection in unit tests that use RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I want to run unit tests, that use RestKit to load objects (into CoreData). But I don't want my unit tests (or RestKit) to actually connect to the server, since the server might not be reachable.

How do I tell RestKit to use a fixture (predefined json file) as the response, instead of connecting to the remote server? I know about RKFixture and [Unit testing with RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Unit-Testing-with-RestKit) but that doesn't cover my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The last answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191714/asihttprequest-backed-restkit-object-mapping) thread may be useful for your specific problem. By the way, have you looked a [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit)? It is a very good unit testing framework that allows for asynchronous unit tests. Typically a server failure should be tested anyway.

If your unit test is designed to test the mapping feature then you have this alternative also:

```
//Create object mapper
RKObjectMapper* mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject: obj  mappingProvider:mappingProvider];
mapper.context = RKObjectMappingProviderContextObjectsByKeyPath;

//Perform mapping
RKObjectMappingResult* mappingResult = [mapper performMapping];

NSArray *results = [mappingResult asCollection]
```

This is basically what happens inside RKObjectLoader. Here obj is some parsed JSON object (NSDictionary or NSArray) that you may create using your test data.

Comment: Thanks, it looks related to my problem, or at least gives me some hints what direction I should be looking. I'll keep you posted.